# git-lfs i/o timeout while pushing code to bitbucket

Tags: git, bitbucket

I use git-lfs for big sized files in git repo. When im trying to push the binaries to repo, git-lfs is going in an infinite loop and tries to upload the files again and again.
Then I enabled trace logs and I see that git-lfs is failing due to i/o timeout error.

> Git LFS: (0 of 8 files) 395.68 MB / 748.90 MB
>   trace git-lfs: tq: retrying object
>   25c358603c20dbd5af29ba6429bd4a1e43df7ac908b32: LFS: Put
>   https://media-api.atlassian.io/upload/fe3853ab-61e8-9e38-a7ac90377129/binary?hashAlgorithm=sha256:
>   read tcp xxx.rr.33.14:61709->xxx.rrr.dd.34:9480: i/o timeout trace
>   git-lfs: tq: enqueue retry #1 for
>   "25c3ac077a0dbd5af29ba6429bd4a1e43df7ac908b32" (size: 121194578) trace
>   git-lfs: HTTP: PUT
>   https://media-api.atlassian.io/upload/0e7801a5-e481-4ad7-b11a-067640/binary
>   Git LFS: (0 of 8 files) 365.18 MB / 748.90 MB

Commands im running -

```
$ git add binaries/
$ git commit -m 'my msg'
$ git push
```

Answer (score 7):

If you look here there are some timeout settings you can try to set.

[Git LFS timeout settings](https://github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/blob/main/docs/man/git-lfs-config.5.ronn)

this is a common problem and you can try to adjust that parameters.

Comment: i hav used lfs.dialtimeout=60 , lfs.tlstimeout=60 and lfs.keepalive=60 but still same error.

Comment: And if you put it much higher to 1 hour for example? Only for testing?

Comment: Do you have some firewall that interrupt your connection?

Comment: Perhaps that Proxy has a timeout?

Comment: finally fixed it - was missing one property lfs.activitytimeout - it's in the master branch. your link was pointing to some other branch, this property was not there.